# Perform recursive call in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, recursion

I have the following oracle stored procedure.

```
    PROCEDURE UPDATE_STUFF (
        IN_ID    IN NUMBER,
        IN_DATE  IN DATE
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF (IN_DATE - PREV_DATE) > 1 THEN
            UPDATE_STUFF(IN_ID, IN_DATE - 1);
        END IF;

        -- DO SOME STUFF
    END;
```

The problem i am facing now is when `(IN_DATE - PREV_DATE) > 1`, it does not wait for the recursive call to finish but it proceed with `--DO SOME STUFF`. Is my recursive call correct? How do i make sure that the recursive call is finish before proceed?

I am using oracle sql developer, 11g.

Comment: `PREV_DATE` is the last date when the record is modified.

Comment: @noobie does the PREV_DATE change everytime the procedure is called recursively?

Comment: I know this is old, but the issue of         Prev_date is the crux. I strongly suspect it's null. When the if test is done, the result is null and causes it to skip entirely. I'd put that in the answer but I'm not entirely sure.         prev_date is either out of scope or a database value that needs to be loaded into a local/global var.